# Invalid Operation error from joining two subqueries containing SUM() functions

Tags: sql, join, sum, ms-access-2007

Suppose (hypothetically) I inherited a database, and in this database is one table to track inventory in my concession stand, `[Purchases]` counts my purchases of inventory as well as purchases that my customers make. It's far from an optimal solution, but it's what exists, and I cannot change it.

Inside `[Purchases]`, there are flags to denote what the change is (inventory bought or inventory sold), and I can query the table to see only purchases or sales, and even totals via `SUM()` (per item, time period, etc.) easily enough.

The table would probably look something like this:

```
   Date    |   Flag   |  ItemNum  |   Item Name   |  Quantity  |  Unit Price
10/19/2015    SOLD         001       SNICKERS        2            $1.00
10/19/2015    BOUGHT       001       SNICKERS        72           $0.40
10/18/2015    SOLD         034       GATORADE24OZ    3            $2.00
10/18/2015    SOLD         021       PRETZEL         1            $2.00
...
```

It's easy enough to work with this data, but if I want to see the per item changes in inventory over a time frame, I would probably query the table twice (once for `SOLD`, and once for `BOUGHT`).

```
SELECT
    Q1.ItemNum,
    Q1.QuantityIn,
    Q2.QuantityOut,
   (Q1.QuantityIn - Q2.QuantityOut) AS QuantityRem
FROM
   (
    SELECT
        ItemNum,
        SUM(Quantity) AS QuantityIn
    FROM Purchases
    WHERE Flag LIKE "BOUGHT"
    GROUP BY ItemNum
   )
    AS Q1
    LEFT JOIN
   (
    SELECT
        ItemNum,
        SUM(Quantity) AS QuantityOut
    FROM Purchases
    WHERE Flag LIKE "SOLD"
    GROUP BY ItemNum
   )
    AS Q2
    ON Q1.ItemNum = Q2.ItemNum
```

This however spits back `Invalid Operation.` instead of the desired results. Both subqueries work on their own, and if I make one subquery into a table first the main query works.

There are of course other ways to solve this problem, but assuming in my non-hypothetical situation I am unable to make `SOLD` quantities negative, `UNION` the subqueries, and take the sum afterwards, is my only option to use temporary tables? Is joining two `SUM()` subqueries not supported in Jet for some reason? I was unable to find anything out when searching for solutions.

Comment: you are missing `,` in the `select`s in sub-queries

Comment: Fixed both, good catches. Sadly, the error is not that simple.

Comment: Note that even if your query did not throw an error, it does not handle the case where items were sold but not bought, and it does not *properly* handle the case where items are bought but not sold (so that `Q2.QuantityOut` of the left-joined result would be `NULL`).

Answer (score 2):

When you say you are unable to make the `SOLD` quantities negative, I suppose you mean you must not alter those quantities *in the base table*.  That does not preclude altering them in the query, however.  Access does not support standard SQL `CASE` expressions, but it does support other conditional expressions.  Thus, you might try something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    ItemNum,
    SUM(IIF(flag = 'BOUGHT', quantity, 0)) AS QuantityIn,
    SUM(IIF(flag <> 'BOUGHT', quantity, 0)) AS QuantityOut,
    SUM(IIF(flag = 'BOUGHT', quantity, -quantity)) AS QuantityChange
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY ItemNum
```

Comment: This idea crossed my mind previously, but I was hesitant to go with it due to the `Flag` field being a lot more complex (for little reason) in the full scale issue. I think it might be easier than I originally thought though. I'll have to get back to this tomorrow though. Thank you for the help, all!